# How to add a many-to-many relationship to Identity default table AspNetUsers with code first?

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-identity-2

I'm new to Identity framework and Code First method. Right now I'm using the default project upon creating a new MVC5 Project on VS 2015.

The default tables generated when I run the project are fine, but I want it to generate a new one called tbSkills (Id, SkillName) alongside the others and it has to have a many-to-many relationship with the AspNetUsers.

So where and what I have to write to accomplish this?

*ps:* I also changed the Id types from string to int after following a tutorial, it worked fine.

This is what I have tried last, inside the class *ApplicationUser*, on the *IdentityModels.cs* file:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, MyUserLogin, MyUserRole, MyUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    // // This following is my added code 
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Skills = new HashSet<tbSkill>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<tbSkill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class tbSkill
{
    public tbSkill()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public int Id;
    public string SkillName;

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

It ends in this error:

[image]

I have already researched and read a bunch of articles, and no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding skill id

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, MyUserLogin, MyUserRole, MyUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    // // This following is my added code 
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Skills = new HashSet<tbSkill>();
    }
    public int SkillId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<tbSkill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```